# Processor too hot? (85º)

Tags: cpu, cooling, thermal-paste

This is my processor:

[image]

I used Speccy to check the heat and it's around 85ºc

[image]

[image]

I've tried changing the thermal paste but it didn't change anything

Comment: If the processor isn't shutting itself down then the temperature is within the specifications of the processor. If the processor is 85º idle then the processor is indeed running hot, without more information, this question cannot be answered.

Comment: What is 85 F/C? if it's F then it's not too high

Comment: Is this an idle temperature? A temperature when the CPU is being heavily utilized? We need more info.

Comment: Yes it stays on 85º C while i'm doing almost nothing on the PC Here's more info: http://i.imgur.com/6OFerdS.png

Comment: Is the cpu fan working?

Comment: Heh, the cooler was not working... Thanks for the answers guys XD

Comment: That is too hot. Maximum Tcase is 73.3 °C. http://ark.intel.com/products/31733/Intel-Pentium-Processor-E2180-1M-Cache-2_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been trivially solved by the question author.

Comment: I don't understand you said it was 85ºc not 75-77ºc that is a **huge** difference.  That 7-10ºc temperature difference is huge.

Comment: It was 85º C when i made the question, i don't know why it's lower now. It is around 70-75 now i don't know why, every single day i checked Speccy and it always was 80-85...

Answer (score 3):

Put your computer in a well ventilated place, with some free room around your computer for heatsinks.

First, leave idle for 20 minutes. Observe temperatures. If it goes beyond 60C, it's definitely a cooling problem. If it's under 50C, it is all okay.

Then do a stress test for 20 minutes, for cpu and gpu separately. If any of them passes 90C, then there is a problem. Otherwise, it's all okay.
Some computers even don't perform well in stress tests, even if they are brand new. So, you need to compare your stress test values to other users values to know if there is a problem.

For GPU Stress test, I recommend Furmark, I like it. But any tool is fine.

So after you did the tests, and if there is a problem, you can do these:

1 - Reapplying thermal paste.

2 - Cleaning heat sinks and fans.

And don't use your computer in dusty places, don't leave tobacco in the table etc.

Comment: We already found the problem, the cooler fan was not working.

Comment: OK. My solution was a universal one. I think others can find it helpful too.